# Identify individual membership in string characters and create columns

Tags: dplyr, case, mutate

I recently asked how to identify row entries according to rows that have matching characters within a string.

I have advanced with the dataset and would like to know how it'd be possible to identify a new type of matched condition for different rows.

Here is how the data looks like:

```
 Date         TimeObserved     IndividualsObserved      Group
 01/01/2018         09.00      Elliot, Azur, Noir       MixedGroup
 01/01/2018         09.00      Azur, Bleue, Rouge       GroupB
 02/01/2018         09.00      Chapman, PJ, Jackson     GroupA
 02/01/2018         09.00      Mississippi, Missouri    GroupC
 03/01/2018         10.00      Eben, Azur, Bleue, Noir  GroupB
 03/01/2018         10.00      Eben, Azur, Bleue        GroupB
 03/01/2018         10.00      Eben, Azur, PJ, Noir     MixedGroup
 03/01/2018         10.00      Chapman, Bowie, Shakira  GroupA
 03/01/2018         10.00      Murray, Mississippi, Mia GroupC
 04/01/2018         10.00      Mississippi, Mia         GroupC
 04/01/2018         10.00      Murray, Azur, Eben       MixedGroup
 04/01/2018         10.00      Shakira, Jackson, Bowie  GroupA
 04/01/2018         10.00      Bleue, Noir, Rouge       GroupB
```

I would like to know how could I obtain matches of entries that have the same date and time WHEN at least one entry is a "MixedGroup" (let's say of group A with group B) as would be the first row.

I have a list of individuals that belong to each group:

```
groupA = c(Chapman, PJ, Jackson, Elliot, Bowie, Shakira)
groupB = c(Azur, Bleue, Rouge, Noir, Eben)
groupC = c(Mississippi, Missouri, Murray, Mia)
```

Could it be possible to create columns that identify the group as Group1 and Group2, or even group3 when there are MixedGroups? Any individual of any of the three groups mixed, it does not matter whether it is one or more) with the matched group/s that is/are mixed (sometimes I don't have data for the two groups involved in a MixedGroup on the same date and hour).

Could there be a way to create a column that says "Match number" (1,2,3,....) that accounts for the number of MixedGroup situations and assigns this number not only to the mixed group but also to rows of the groups involved in the mixed group having the same date and hour?

The desired output table would look like this:

```
 Date         TimeObserved     IndividualsObserved      Group        Group1  Group2  MatchNumber
 01/01/2018         09.00      Elliot, Azur, Noir       MixedGroup      A      B       1
 01/01/2018         09.00      Azur, Bleue, Rouge       GroupB          B      NA      1
 02/01/2018         09.00      Chapman, PJ, Jackson     GroupA          B      NA      1  
 02/01/2018         09.00      Mississippi, Missouri    GroupC          C      NA      NA 
 03/01/2018         10.00      Rouge, Bleue, Noir       GroupB          B      NA      2  
 03/01/2018         10.00      Eben, Azur, PJ, Noir     MixedGroup      B      A       2 
 03/01/2018         10.00      Chapman, Bowie, Shakira  GroupA          A      NA      2  
 03/01/2018         10.00      Murray, Mississippi, Mia GroupC          C      NA      3     
 04/01/2018         10.00      Missouri, Azur, Eben     MixedGroup      C      B       3  
 04/01/2018         10.00      Shakira, Jackson, Bowie  GroupA          A      NA      NA
 04/01/2018         10.00      Bleue, Noir, Rouge       GroupB          B      NA      3
```

Thanks a lot if you have any insights,

Comment: Hi can you explain the MatchNumber column a bit? for example, how does the last row have a 3 in it?

Comment: It'd be an identifier, so if there is a MixedGroup on date 04/01/2018 (3rd last row) between GroupA and GroupB, then the MatchedNumber identifies with same number both:
1st)MixedGroup
2nd) each one of the groups that is represented by at least one individual from them in the MixedGroup which would be any entries, if they exist, with same Date and Time that in that example would be GroupB and GroupC on their respective rows.

Comment: hi sorry I don't follow at all. That row is not *between* any, it's the first row of the date 04/01/2018

Comment: maybe instead explain why some rows have NAs. For example, rows 1, 2, and 3 are Mixed Group, A and B, and the number is 1 in all rows. In contrast, in the last three, it is 3, NA, 3, for mysterious reasons I cannot comprehend

Comment: Hi, I aim to have the group identifier of the IndividualsObserved column in the Group 1 and Group 2 columns. If there is only one group, that´d go in the group1 column; if it´s a mixed group, the two columns would have a group.
The matched number aims to identify rows with the same date and time for mixed group cases and the associated groups that are not mixed but are present in a separate row at the exact date and time. This number is assigned to both the mixed group and the non- mixed groups that are part of the mixed group. That number should be a series number (starting from 1).

Comment: this doesn't actually help me, or answer my question at all. Rows 1, 2, and 3 are Mixed Group, A and B, and the number is 1 in all rows. In contrast, in the last three, it is 3, NA, 3, despite also containing, A, B, and MixedGroup, for mysterious reasons I cannot comprehend. Why?